# Magento Fitler based on Custom Attribute

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, attributes, module, dropdown-attribute

I SAW LOT OF POSTS ON Stackoverflow & here also , I **DIDN'T get SINGLE** proper answer.

Hi dudes,
I have Filter option when i goto other Category->Product listing page .

I want to make it like Sort Dropdown of magento by default.

I have custom attr. as Carat for golden shop . I set its value from backend ,like 14,15 etc.

I m fetching it properly in drop down.

What should be done if i want to filter products by `Carat` ?

Till now my code to fetch Custom attr. & show in DDList.

```
    <!--Modified Code 27 Oct-->
    <?php 
        $name='carat_dropdown';
        $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')->setCodeFilter($name)->getFirstItem();
        $attributeId = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();                                    
        $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
        $attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
    ?>

    <div class="sort-by">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Filter By') ?></label>
        <select name="filterByCaret" >
                <option value="" >Select</option>                         
            <?php
            foreach($attributeOptions as $single){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $single['value']?>" >                         
                    <?php echo $single['label']?>
                </option>          
            <?php
            }                                   
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>        
    <!--//Modified Code 27 Oct-->
```

DDList = Drop Down List.

**Even in simple way**

. Hi see, i have custom field in backend for jewellery shop `Caret Value`  .So in drop down i will have all values i enter from backend for Carat Value like 13,14 etc. So in front end i want to show DDList ,and if i select 14 , products with Carat value 14 will be filtered &shown
Thanks for help.

Comment: First of all, what is a 'DDList' list? Second, you mean this like a layered navigation kind of filtering? It sounds like you just need to make this an anchor category and use default Magento functionality

Comment: @SanderMangel , DDList-> DropDownList

Comment: @SanderMangel . Hi see, i have custom field in backend for jewellery shop `Caret Value`  .So in drop down i will have all values i enter from backend for Carat Value like 13,14 etc. So in front end i want to show DDList ,and if i select 14 , products with Carat value 14 will be filtered &shown

Comment: Ok but why not use the layered navigation? Make the caret value a filterable product attribute and have it show up in layered navigation?

Comment: @SanderMangel ok no problem, already i m fed up with magento . NO clear docs, Question asked is what is ABC , answers explain What is XYZ . PRETTY MESSY

Comment: Answering a question clearly in Magento often requires a deeper understanding of the framework than someone new to the framework  probably has - although it may appear a simple question with a simple answer it isn't necessarily the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you are discribing the functionality it sounds like you want layered navigation. In this case you should make an attribute for `caret value` and make it dropdown and filterable. Then set the category to `anchor`.

Below is some information about layered navigation

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PQhITHhWUk
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/filterable-attributes
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-does-layered-navigation-work

Comment: Thanks bro , cheers you made my day.I see lot of Confusion related to Majento coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('carat', 'value');
```

Just edit `value` to be the value of the attribute you are interested in.

FYI, starting your question with a row of capitals and bold lettering doesn't overly encourage people to help you...

Comment: Now Where to add this line ? Which file shuld be edited ? what folder to open to open this file ?Will it work with view i have ? I have <form> and just besides Sort menu, there is filter menu .Will it work with phtml i made? Do i need to create any module ?

Thanks